# Product carousel does not contain only <li> elements according to pagespeed.web.dev

Tags: magento2

when i run a test of our website on Googles pagespeed.web.dev , it will tell me the following feedback on Magentos own Product Carousel.

`Lists do not contain only <li> elements and script supporting elements (<script> and <template>).`

and

`List items (<li>) are not contained within <ul>, <ol> or <menu> parent elements.`

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Seems it has to do with the arrow keys and also something else.